# Capture output of a script in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am running the following Workflow

```
      - name: perform checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.6.0

      - name: run the script
        shell: bash
        run: echo "EXECUTION_OUTPUT=$(./script.sh)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: parse the output
        shell: bash
        run: echo $EXECUTION_OUTPUT
```

Where `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Τhis is before"

echo ====================  Rules Evaluation Report  ====================

echo "This is after"
```

The workflow fails as follows:

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiline strings, you may use a delimiter, as described in the [doc here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings). So try this code:

```
  - name: Set the value in bash
    run: |
      {
        echo 'EXECUTION_OUTPUT<<EOF'
        ./script.sh
        echo EOF
      } >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

  - name: parse the output
    shell: bash
    run: echo $EXECUTION_OUTPUT
```

Reproduced and tested [here](https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/tree/test-script). See this [run](https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/actions/runs/6039554681)

Comment: If I see correctly (and this is also what I experience) is that newlines are not preserved. Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you tried this? https://medium.com/@ibraheemabukaff/github-actions-exporting-multi-line-one-line-value-environment-variable-5bb86d01e866

Comment: I just did, it still displays it in one line